# How to set custom status inside dota2 (Which shows in the friends' section)

Tags: dota-2

I have seen one of my friends with a custom status in the area (it switches from "Main Menu" to "Looking to play" every few seconds). How to do this? (I dont care about the switching part much, just how to tell people I want to be invited for a party).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On your DotA 2 profile, right under your Pseudo, you have a text zone (with a pencil) where you can edit you status. See image below :

[image]

The game will alternate your custom status with your current status in the game (in menu, searching for a game, waiting for players to load etc.).